# protractor test gets to timeout

Tags: authentication, timeout, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm running a login test on protractor.
the login page is non angular, but the rest is.
after the login, in order to make sure it passed, I'm searching for specific element in the page and it gets into timeout after a while.

the Test:

```
it('Should login using Email & Password', function () {
   browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userName_str')).sendKeys("testmail@testmail.com");
   browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys("Password");
   browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//input[contains(@value,'Log In')]")).click();


   expect($('[data-ui-sref="myApps"]').isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

this is what I get after a while (after the user logged in and I see the home page):

```
login Testing Should login using Email & Password
Message:
 timeout: timed out after 30000 msec waiting for spec to complete
Stacktrace:
 undefined
```

worth to mention that I'm using

```
onPrepare: function() {
// for non-angular page
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
}
```

in the configuration file.

any help would be appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: Hey,apparently it happens only on Chrome, but on FF it works. any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ignoreSynchronization` back to default `false` value.

I think you should do it in the `afterEach()` inside the spec:

```
describe("My test", function () {

    afterEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    });

    it('Should login using Email & Password', function () {
         browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;      

         browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userName_str')).sendKeys("testmail@testmail.com");
         browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys("Password");
         browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//input[contains(@value,'Log In')]")).click();

         expect($('[data-ui-sref="myApps"]').isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

Comment: got the same results. I'm still not sure exactly how to use the ignoreSynchronization parameter and whether it's related to my problem.

Comment: @user2880391 okay, do you know on which line does it hang?

Comment: yes. after the          browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//input[contains(@value,'Log In')]")).click();    it directed to homepage and then it hangs.

Comment: @user2880391 okay, what if you add `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;` right after this line, then add `browser.waitForAngular()`?

Comment: @user2880391 what if you comment the `expect()` line?

Comment: @user2880391 that's probably it, try adding `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;`  and `browser.waitForAngular();` before the expect call.

Comment: @user2880391 also, try this expect: `expect(element(by.css('[data-ui-sref=myApps]')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);`

Comment: I'm not sure it's the best practice, and maybe some stuff changed since I asked the question, but currently this part consists of the following (and it works):  browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userName_str')).sendKeys("testmail@testmail.com");
         browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys("Password");
         browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//input[contains(@value,'Log In')]")).click();
browser.sleep(5000);
       browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
     
       browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
       
       flow.timeout(5000);